# Cannot correctly position horizontal list inline with <a>'s?

Tags: html, css, web, positioning

So basically I'm doing a layout with a large image feature, that can move from one picture to another using arrows beneath. Honestly it's quite a lot like the front page of flipboard.com, in regard to the picture feature.

```css
.feature-nav {
        width: 234px;   
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    .prev-arrow {
        display: inline;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #B6B6B6;
    }
    
    .prev-arrow:hover {
        color: #428bca;
    }
    
    .feature-nav ul {
        display: inline;  
    }
    
    .feature-nav li {
        display: inline;
    }
    
    .nav-dot a {
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #B6B6B6;
    }
    
    .next-arrow { 
        display: inline;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #B6B6B6;
    }
    
    .next-arrow:hover {
        color: #428bca;   
    }
```

```html
<div class="feature-nav">
            <a href="#" class="prev-arrow">&lt;</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-dot"><a href="#">&#8226;</a></li>
                <li class="nav-dot"><a href="#">&#8226;</a></li>
                <li class="nav-dot"><a href="#">&#8226;</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="next-arrow">&gt;</a>
        </div>
```

The output:

[image]

Does anyone know why the dots and right arrow are so far shifted from the left arrow? I've tried adjusting padding, margins, the "left: " property, and all of them work accept the make the left arrow not select properly, it only recognizes that you're hovering over it if you hover over a very small certain area. Right now, with the shown code, it doesn't do that, but the positioning is off. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because unordered lists have a default padding that you can get rid of by adding `padding:0` to your `.feature-nav ul` rules:

```css
.feature-nav {
        width: 234px;   
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    .prev-arrow {
        display: inline;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #B6B6B6;
    }
    
    .prev-arrow:hover {
        color: #428bca;
    }
    
    .feature-nav ul {
        display: inline;  
        padding:0;
    }
    
    .feature-nav li {
        display: inline;
    }
    
    .nav-dot a {
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #B6B6B6;
    }
    
    .next-arrow { 
        display: inline;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #B6B6B6;
    }
    
    .next-arrow:hover {
        color: #428bca;   
    }
```

```html
<div class="feature-nav">
            <a href="#" class="prev-arrow">&lt;</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-dot"><a href="#">•</a></li>
                <li class="nav-dot"><a href="#">•</a></li>
                <li class="nav-dot"><a href="#">•</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="next-arrow">&gt;</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! So simple, so elegant, so Best Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: inline-block` for the arrows and list items, and give them padding for a larger "hit" area for when hovering. You can also set a right or left `margin` for the arrows or list items to separate them a bit as well.

As for why they're off-center, remove padding from the `ul` element.

As for the

```css
.feature-nav {
        width: 234px;   
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    .prev-arrow {
        display: inline-block;
        padding 10px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        font-size: 30px;

        color: #B6B6B6;
    }
    
    .prev-arrow:hover {
        color: #428bca;
    }
    
    .feature-nav ul {
        display: inline;  
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .feature-nav li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 5px;
    }
    
    .nav-dot a {
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #B6B6B6;
    }
    
    .next-arrow { 
        display: inline-block;
        padding 10px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #B6B6B6;
    }
    
    .next-arrow:hover {
        color: #428bca;   
    }
```

```html
<div class="feature-nav">
            <a href="#" class="prev-arrow">&lt;</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-dot"><a href="#">•</a></li>
                <li class="nav-dot"><a href="#">•</a></li>
                <li class="nav-dot"><a href="#">•</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="next-arrow">&gt;</a>
        </div>
```